# How to use pandas apply to create custom sequence

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I need to add a column to a python pandas data frame that contains a sequence of numbers. The numbers mostly are incremented by a number, but sometimes the pattern breaks and it is set to a fixed number…other times it increments by a much larger number.  Bottom line is I clearly can’t use `groupby` and `rank` for that.
I want to create a custom function and use `apply` to execute it, but how do I ensure the output of each row is used in the next row without looping? Example:

```
10
15
20
200
205
210
215
```

If I have to instead use `itertuples` to loop, would the fastest way to do that be create a `series` and then convert the `series` to a column after the looping is over? The `df` row count is about `160k`.

Here is a sample script of how I can loop through the rows.  What I'd like to do is use the apply method (or vectorization) instead.  Is it possible?

```
import pandas as pd
import re

# Sample (fake) function
def create_sequence(id, sub_id, previous_sequence):
    # EDIT:  Added reset to 5 if sub_id = 1 after first two answers were already given
    if sub_id == 1:
        sequence = 5
    elif re.match('^4.*', id) and sub_id == 3:
        sequence = previous_sequence + 200
    elif re.match('^T.*', id) and sub_id == 6:
        sequence = previous_sequence + 60
    else:
        sequence = previous_sequence + 5

    return sequence

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'main_id': '4G5KW5', 'irrelevant_field': 'WT', 'sub_id': 1},
    {'main_id': '4G5KW5', 'irrelevant_field': 'WR', 'sub_id': 2},
    {'main_id': '4G5KW5', 'irrelevant_field': 'WR', 'sub_id': 3},
    {'main_id': '4G5KW5', 'irrelevant_field': 'WG', 'sub_id': 4},
    {'main_id': 'T3OFB2', 'irrelevant_field': 'WT', 'sub_id': 1},
    {'main_id': 'T3OFB2', 'irrelevant_field': 'WT', 'sub_id': 2},
    {'main_id': 'T3OFB2', 'irrelevant_field': 'WG', 'sub_id': 3},
    {'main_id': 'T3OFB2', 'irrelevant_field': 'WT', 'sub_id': 4},
    {'main_id': 'T3OFB2', 'irrelevant_field': 'WS', 'sub_id': 5},
    {'main_id': 'T3OFB2', 'irrelevant_field': 'WS', 'sub_id': 6},
    {'main_id': 'T3OFB2', 'irrelevant_field': 'WS', 'sub_id': 7},
    {'main_id': 'T3OFB2', 'irrelevant_field': 'WT', 'sub_id': 8},
    {'main_id': 'T3OFB2', 'irrelevant_field': 'WR', 'sub_id': 9}
])

# Ideally I'd like to do something like this, although I know create_sequence
# would have to be modified to accept only row as an argument
# df[sequence] = df.apply(create_sequence, axis=1)

# Loop approach:
seq_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['main_id', 'sub_id', 'sequence'])
prev_sequence = 0
for row in df.itertuples():
    main_id = row[1]
    sub_id = row[3]
    sequence = create_sequence(main_id, sub_id, prev_sequence)
    print(main_id, sub_id, sequence)
    seq_df.loc[len(seq_df.index)] = [main_id, sub_id, sequence]
    prev_sequence = sequence


final_df = pd.merge(df.astype(str, skipna=False), seq_df.astype(str, skipna=False), how='left', on=['main_id', 'sub_id'])
print(final_df)
```

Final results:

```
   main_id irrelevant_field sub_id sequence
0   4G5KW5               WT      1        5
1   4G5KW5               WR      2       10
2   4G5KW5               WR      3      210
3   4G5KW5               WG      4      215
4   T3OFB2               WT      1        5
5   T3OFB2               WT      2       10
6   T3OFB2               WG      3       15
7   T3OFB2               WT      4       20
8   T3OFB2               WS      5       25
9   T3OFB2               WS      6       85
10  T3OFB2               WS      7       90
11  T3OFB2               WT      8       95
12  T3OFB2               WR      9      100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the previous value of `sub_id`, use `shift` – it shifts the whole column down by one row:

```py
>>> df['prev_sub_id'] = df.sub_id.shift(fill_value=0)
>>> df.head()
   main_id irrelevant_field  sub_id  prev_sub_id
0   4G5KW5               WT       1            0
1   4G5KW5               WR       2            1
2   4G5KW5               WR       3            2
3   4G5KW5               WG       4            3
4   T3OFB2               WT       1            4
```

**But** it seems you don't really need that here.

Instead, you can use a cumulative sum. Set `5` as the default value to add per row. Then, update the rows where the values to increment are different:

```py
>>> df['sequence'] = 5
>>> df.loc[df.main_id.str.startswith('4') & df.sub_id.eq(3), 'sequence'] = 200
>>> df.loc[df.main_id.str.startswith('T') & df.sub_id.eq(6), 'sequence'] = 60
>>> df.head()
   main_id irrelevant_field  sub_id  prev_sub_id  sequence
0   4G5KW5               WT       1            0         5
1   4G5KW5               WR       2            1         5
2   4G5KW5               WR       3            2       200
3   4G5KW5               WG       4            3         5
4   T3OFB2               WT       1            4         5
```

Finally, add them up with `cumsum`.

```py
>>> df['sequence'] = df.sequence.cumsum()
>>> df
   main_id irrelevant_field  sub_id  sequence
0   4G5KW5               WT       1         5
1   4G5KW5               WR       2        10
2   4G5KW5               WR       3       210
3   4G5KW5               WG       4       215
4   T3OFB2               WT       1       220
5   T3OFB2               WT       2       225
6   T3OFB2               WG       3       230
7   T3OFB2               WT       4       235
8   T3OFB2               WS       5       240
9   T3OFB2               WS       6       300
10  T3OFB2               WS       7       305
11  T3OFB2               WT       8       310
12  T3OFB2               WR       9       315
```

---

The operation can be performed on groups, e.g.,

```py
def set_sequence(frame):
    frame['sequence'] = 5
    frame.loc[frame.main_id.str.startswith('4') & frame.sub_id.eq(3), 'sequence'] = 200
    frame.loc[frame.main_id.str.startswith('T') & frame.sub_id.eq(6), 'sequence'] = 60
    frame['sequence'] = frame.sequence.cumsum()
    
    return frame

>>> df.groupby('main_id').apply(set_sequence)
   main_id irrelevant_field  sub_id  sequence
0   4G5KW5               WT       1         5
1   4G5KW5               WR       2        10
2   4G5KW5               WR       3       210
3   4G5KW5               WG       4       215
4   T3OFB2               WT       1         5
5   T3OFB2               WT       2        10
6   T3OFB2               WG       3        15
7   T3OFB2               WT       4        20
8   T3OFB2               WS       5        25
9   T3OFB2               WS       6        85
10  T3OFB2               WS       7        90
11  T3OFB2               WT       8        95
12  T3OFB2               WR       9       100
```

Comment: Thanks!  I think it was off by 5 because I accidentally started with 5 (+5 = 10).  Hypothetically speaking, if sequence were to reset to 5 every time the main_id changes, I guess I could use cumsum within groupby?  (Sorry I forgot to mention that part, I will update the example.)

Comment: @compx You mean like in my edit? Don't get me wrong, but this is the second time you omitted an essential part of the problem. Please make sure you include all important aspects when asking because even though I and many others enjoy coming up with solutions, it's frustrating to spend half an hour on a problem only to get a comment along the lines of "actually, I need something else".

Comment: I know I'd be very frustrated if the roles were reversed, I am sorry for that.  I will make sure to be more careful of that in the future.  Thank you very much for taking the time to come up with your solution; you should get "bonus points" for the fact it's a solution without looping.  (I don't have enough of a reputation to vote for it.)